# Raw HTML in a Multiline text field in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: jss, sitecore-api

I created a new field in a template, it is a  Multi-Line Text(name html field).

I created a component and added on the page. I go to experience editor. click on the component to edit it. The  html field comes up. I add the raw html markup and save. Instead of showing HELLO it shows the whole HTML markup:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how i am using in jss `*scText="rendering?.fields?.Html" >`

Using sitecore ver 9.3. What do i need to do so it doesn't show the raw html?

Comment: I would try to rename your field to something else than Html...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a rich text field instead and use the "Edit HTML" button, multi-line text is meant for plain text.

Also showing HTML code in a field like that will be confusing for a content author.